# How to listen on a port and broadcast from another at the same time? Python

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, python-3.5

I have a python script which works very well at listening for a UDP packet on a port. 
I already know how to broadcast a UDP packet but the design of my software would require me to be able to listen for a UDP packet and broadcast them at the same time.

How can I listen on one port for UDP packets, whilst the program continues, ultimatly resulting broadcasting of packets?

Simply put, I would like my listening loop....

```
    print("Listening on port: " + str(self.recvPort))
    while 1:
        data = inSoc.recv(65536)  # 16 bytes
        # Recived some data from the server, Can PROCCESS NOW!
    if not data:
        pass
    else:
        print("Data has arrived!")
        print("[Data] : ", data)
```

... to continuously run in the background while the script continues its other tasks, one being to broadcast out on a different port.

I know this should be relational to threading, _thread or async however I am unable to get these to work?

I named the loop an `async def` but it failed due to not having an `await`

Comment: I'd say you should really take a look at celery. If it has to be within a single script you'd need to use separate processors since certain operations can be blocking. If you have to share state between the 2 then you'd want to use something like a manager dict.

Comment: I'd like it in the same script most definatly

Comment: Then you'll have to run separate processors (thanks gil) but with a manager dict https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes that shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't inherently need threading to solve this.
I think you should have a look at **select** https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

then you could do something like:

```
while 1:
    read, _, _ = select.select([inSoc],[],[], 0)
    #if insoc has something for you to read
    for soc in read:
        data = soc.recv(65536)
    #do something else
```

Comment: This seems good. Just so I can understand your code. `read` will contain queued objects of any packets, if there are no packets in the queue it will continue with the while loop?

Comment: read will contain a list of sockets which are ready to be read from, aka have received something. since we only send in inSoc this will mean that either read will be empty or contain insoc. then for each socket that had something to read( aka none or insoc) we do recv. After which we go do something else before looping.